# XPATH to validate the content of the text

Tags: html, selenium, dom, xpath

I have the below piece of HTML.

```
HTML Code: 
<a id="pINumber" href="csf.ajax?et=p.preparationinsurance">PASS170XX</a>

XPATH to identify the above element
//*[@id="pINumber"]
```

I'm trying to build an XPATH which can validate the Text 'PASS' is always present as Text in the beginning . What would be the XPATH in such cases.

After few searches about the XPATH, i could see that `"substring-after"` can be used to do this. But couldn't prepare the right XPATH. Any help to build an XPATH for the above HTML with a text 'PASS' as part of verification that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this XPath:

```
starts-with(a/text(),'PASS')
```

It checks if the `text()` of the link `a` does start with the char-sequence `PASS`. In your case this evaluates to `true`.

And in a whole expression this can be

```
//a[starts-with(text(),'PASS')]
```

Comment: If you want to retrieve the value of the text which is 'PASS' than what would be the xpath?

Comment: It would be the same, possibly with a `/text()` at the end like `//a[starts-with(text(),'PASS')]/text()`.

Comment: //a[starts-with(text(),'PASS')]/text() will return the complete text , I want to just make the XPATH such that it returns "170XX" instead of "PASS170XX"

Comment: Then the expression can be `substring(//a[starts-with(text(),'PASS')],5)`.

Comment: Does it help to add a `[1]` to the end like `substring(//a[starts-with(text(),'PASS')][1],5)`?

Comment: This worked for me "//a[substring-after(text(),'PASS')]"

Comment: If you are familiar with this, try `substring-after(//a[substring-after(text(),'PASS')],'PASS')`. Are you ok with a chat?